# Interactive Select from List in Powershell

Tags: powershell, menu

Is there a plugin or tool that will let me display a list of objects to a user (`Format-Table` style) and allow them to use the cursor to select a choice from the list, including potentially scrolling a long list? I would like to be able to do something like this:

`Get-User -anr $search |`**`Get-Choice`**`| Set-User -EnableAccount true`

This script should display a list of matching accounts at a console prompt, allow the user to scroll up and down the list interactively, and select a choice by pressing Enter (or pass null if the user hits escape). Only one account would be passed to Set-User, rather than a list of all matching choices.

Obviously details could differ. While I would prefer a console version, a graphical one would be acceptable (that popped up a Windows dialog). The exact keystrokes could be different. But the core goal (accepting a list, getting user input, piping out the result) should be met.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

in **v3**:

```
Get-User -anr $search | Out-GridView -PassThru | Set-User -EnableAccount true
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you @walid2mi! I don't mind installing the PSv3 beta on my client machine, and this is a far cleaner implementation than the more compatible Out-Form functon suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to [Out-Form](http://poshcode.org/2628)

pseudo use:

```
out-form -title "Enable Account" -data (Get-user -anr $search) -columnNames ("AccountName") `
    -columnProperties ("SamAccountName") -actions @{Enable It!" = { $_ | Set-User -EnableAccount true}}
```